# Report Application Pascal - Variable value not being shown correctly

Tags: report, pascal, delphi

I'm building a report using Report Builder. It uses Report Application Pascal, which is based on Delphi Object Pascal. I'm still learning this and struggling with a variable value.

I have a variable called 'duration' which contains the following script:

```
value := round(ReportWizardQuery['wodFinishDate'] - ReportWizardQuery    
['wodCreateDate']);
```

This gives me the result I want. It calculates the total number of days between the two dates.

What I'm trying to do then is to use the value of this 'duration' variable to find out if jobs (which are defined by the start and end date) have been completed on the same day, within 1-5 days, 6-10 days, etc.

I've created columns with these headings and placed a varible in each column in the detail band of the report. The code I have written in the variable for 'same-day' is:

```
if (duration = 0) then
value := 1;
```

Likewise for jobs being completed between 1 - 5 days

```
if (duration > 0 and < 6) then
value := 1;
```

But variables are blank when report run. I have tried to assign the value of the 'duration' variable to that of the same-day variable and it returns a weird number which is the the same for each line in the report (99468080, or 10150660...etc) This number changes each time I run the report and always seems to be 8 digits long.

Does anybody have any idea what I'm doing wrong and how I can assign the value 1 for each variable if the duration variable = 0, or between 1 - 5, etc.

Thanks.

Comment: One would think you'd assign the value of 'duration' with something like `duration := ..` and not `value := ..`, but I don't know what kind of script Report Builder uses. Also the 'between' would be more like `if (duration > 0) and (duration < 6) then` for pascal instead of `if (duration > 0 and < 6) then`, but the same argument applies..

Comment: it's a drag and drop interface. So variable is dropped onto report and then you write code for it. The value := is auto generated so you can assign anything to it to give the value for the variable. This bit works OK as it generates the difference in days - maybe it's a problem with data types? Not sure

Comment: A data type issue should not cause your getting different values at different runs for the same expression/values.

Comment: What is the back end database being used? It's often much easier to get the results first in an SQL query, and then just use the report software to do the presentation of those results.

Comment: Back end is SQL server.